# comment for html does not work in react native

Tags: react-native

I have below lines of code in react native and trying to comment the Stack.Navigator block

I tried this using multi line comments with /* */

but this is not working. Is there any way to comment html in react native?

```
<NavigationContainer>
    /*<Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home Screen" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>*/
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not straight html, it just looks like html :D
It is called JSX, and have its own rules. One of them is the commenting.

Looks like you already have learned that you use {} inside a JSX code to put javascript on it. So the commenting is basically enbracing the JSX code you want to comment into {} and then commenting that.

```
{/*<Text>example<Text>*/}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use {/* ... */} syntax since it is JSX.

You can refer to this [link](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-comments/).

```
<NavigationContainer>
    {/*<Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home Screen" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>*/}
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```